# How should I interpret "uncertain one" in this title?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"A consequential choice for France—and an uncertain one"

This is the title of the article about the French election. From this title I interpret that French people must make an extremely important choice in the coming election, and that it is not clear which candidate can make their lives better. Is my understanding appropriate?

*April 22, 2017, The French election, [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21721143-french-go-polls-they-are-angry-and-divided-consequential-choice-franceand)*

Comment: I see no reason to extend the intended sense to imply *that it is not clear which candidate can make their lives better*. The obvious uncertainty is simply that no-one (specifically, the media as represented by the author of the article) has any idea ***what the eventual choice will be***, once the votes are all counted.

Answer (score 2):

The **choice** is BOTH consequential and uncertain. What choice? The choice of president. As a member has rightly pointed out, it simply means that the outcome is not clear yet, to begin with. HOWEVER, the further interpretation you suggested may well be valid, depending on the content, tone and context of what was written. To freely paraphrase Occam's razor (taking some liberties with the scope of the meaning) it is not advisable to make a further interpretation than is necessarily suggested by the article in question!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I particularly like the idea of keeping the principle of Occam's razor!

Comment: @Bakebake - You could accept it (click on the checkmark).